# C++ passing dynamic array element to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, dynamic, arguments

The code looks like this:

```
void fUnc(float b){
  //does nothing  
}

float* fInit(void){
  float result[3];
  result[0] = 1.0;
  result[1] = 1.0;
  result[2] = 1.0;

  return result;
}

int main(){
  float* a = new float[3];
  a = fInit();
  fUnc(a[0]);
  printf("%f, %f, %f", a[0], a[1], a[2]);

  return 0;
}
```

Values of array elements are -107374176.000000. Everything works well if fUnc(a[0]) [which does nothing] is commented out. What's the problem?

EDIT: the code is edited a bit to your better understanding

Comment: What's the need for `new`?

Comment: Your code works for me with g++

Comment: For me, [this works as expected](http://ideone.com/bNj9oe).

Comment: Is this the ACTUAL code that goes wrong, or is this a minimized example, of something that goes wrong when it's not minimized?

Comment: After quick editing the code in the question you should first try if the problem is fixed by the edit. Therefore I am deleting my answer.

Comment: Have you trying cast floats do doubles (because printf %f expect double, not float)? For example: printf( "%f, %f, %f", static_cast<double>(a[0]), /*etc...*/

Comment: @user1837009, Already implicitly done.

Comment: chris, "new" is needed, because the assignment of new memory address (to "a") doesn't work otherwise

Comment: I realise your problem has dramatically changed since your edit, all posted comments and answers are invalid. Please don't edit your problem so much in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return a raw array like that. What your `fInit()` does is to return the address of some local memory that is invalidated once the function returns.

Your `a` then, in some sense, points to memory inside your `fInit()`, but which is not valid anymore. Any attempt to read an element `a[n]` results in undefined behaviour.

You should use one of the standard containers, e.g. a `std::vector` if the size of the array is determined at runtime, or `std::array` if you know the size at compile time. If you need chained lists, use `std::list`, and so on.

All of the standard containers are copyable (and thus returnable).

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container.

And, **definitely bookmark** http://en.cppreference.com/w/. And every time you are tempted to write yourself an [algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), or find yourself invoking `new`, look into the reference. And [get good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)!